# Downfalls of using ASP.NET MVC with Datasets (.xsds)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm needing to add a web application to an already existing solution where Datasets are in play.

I know that the preferred method is EF, and I get that. I'm planning on moving forward with MVC and utilizing the already existent datasets, but I'm curious if there are any actual downfalls with going this route. Or anything that I should take into consideration or to be mindful of before I start?

Any thoughts are appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony, for basic stuffs datasets are fine, but if you need anything more complex, like a more advanced SQL sentence, you will see yourself having to build lots of workaronds, once they don't have a good support for relationships.

Comment: Hm ok. Thanks for the response. Would you have any more examples of what would fall into "anything complex"? I'm not an advocate of Datasets, personally I'd rather use EF, but I'm just trying to figure out what the actual complexities are with using MVC and datasets outside of "it'd be rough for ya bud."

Comment: As it doesn't support relationships, anything with more than onde table would be too complex.

Comment: And boom goes the dynamite. Thanks for the info guys.